# Why does IE 8 load the <head> tag below the <body> tag doesn't occur on IE 7 and 9

Tags: html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

The title explains it all. Here are the screenshots I've got on

IE8: http://screencast.com/t/Sc4XXe8jFfu9

IE7: http://screencast.com/t/xeyRCzXN3

It's a bit weird but it's causing a lot of css issue on my website since the precedence is not correct.

TIA

**EDIT**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $this->getThemePath();?>/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $this->getThemePath();?>/css/responsive-nav-media.css" /> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $this->getThemePath();?>/css/responsive-nav.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $this->getStyleSheet('typography.css')?>" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $this->getStyleSheet('main.css')?>" />
    <!--[if IE]>
    <style type="text/css">
        body#theme-wrapper #header {
            position: relative;
        }
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $this->getThemePath();?>/css/ie.css" />
    <![endif]-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->getThemePath();?>/js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->getThemePath();?>/js/grayscale.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        Modernizr.load([
          {
            test : Modernizr.mq('only all'),
            nope : '<?php echo $this->getThemePath();?>/js/respondjs.js'
          }
        ]);
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->getThemePath();?>/js/responsive-nav.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->getThemePath();?>/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,100,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

Comment: Do you have any javascript that would cause this? Also, your DOCTYPE is commented out, is that correct? It should be <!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: @DavidHoude The doctype is commented out by IE's developer tool. There's no apparent javascript errors. I'm using modernzr respond jquery scripts.

Comment: It doesn't happen with other sites, so it's something specific to your web page. Hard for us to say what since you haven't posted any code.

Comment: @Barmar I've added my header code. Hope that helps clarify things. Thanks!

Comment: Instead of screenshots and fragments of the PHP file, you should post a self-contained document and/or a URL.